# Send Calendar invite email to attendees

Tags: php, gmail, gmail-api, google-calendar-api

I am creating an appointment booking tool for a business owner and I have successfully inserted the calendar in Google calendar of the business owner and sent an invite to appointment attendee.

Some of the issues I face despite enabling notifications while inserting the event are - 
a. The attendee receives an email but the owner doesn't although it is inserted into his calendar. 
b. Once the owner accepts the meeting, I would like to send a confirmation email to the attendee but the attendees are not notified by Google Calendar when an owner accepts. The owner gets notifications when attendees accept though.

So,
a. After I insert an event to the Calendar, I want to send an explicit email to the owner which will give option to accept the meeting.
b. I want to manually send email updates to attendees confirming the appointment in addition to the initial invitation email.

Is there a way, I can send an email the Calendar invite manually thru perhaps gmail? Also, I don't want to send an attachment which needs to be opened to see the updates. I want the user to be able to see it as soon as he opens the email and also automatically update the corresponding entry in his Calendar that may already be present.

(I am using PHP)

Kishan

Comment: When sending invite to the attendees, did you also include the email of the owner?

Comment: Yeah.. I did. I added the owner also as one of the attendees. But, he doesn't  get an explicit email.